# While installing Android studio am getting dialog box obection with text as org.jetbrains.android plugin is missing windows 10

Tags: android

While installing Android studio am getting dialog box objection with text as org.jetbrains.android plugin is missing windows 10.

Am not able to find disabledplugin.txt.
Can anyone please answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled but still getting that dialog box. Please solve this